# How many records? In a file (streaming)

Tags: files-and-directories, streams, counting

I want to know how many records a file (large data) contains...
with streaming...like this:

```
str = OpenRead[
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2015-08.csv"
]

Count[Read[str, {Word, Number}]]
```

but nothing happens...

Comment: Maybe use `Length` instead of `Count`? Or `Count[bla, _]`? Still, `Read[str, {Word, Number}]` is not what you think it is...

Comment: @HenrikSchumachert thank you... Length still doesn't work though

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
str = OpenRead["https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2015-08.csv"]
records = ReadList[str, {Record}];
Close[str];
Length[records]
```

would do it but that would imply that the whole file gets downloaded...

Alternatively, you can use

```
str = OpenRead["https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2015-08.csv"]
c = 0;
Dynamic[c]
record = "";
While[record =!= EndOfFile,
  c++;
  record = Read[str, {Record}];
  ];
Close[str]
```

This also loads the whole file, but it keeps only one record in memory. Better use that only for files on your local drive.

A *recursive* variant could look like this (first an example data set)

```
Export["a.csv", StringSplit[ExampleData[{"Text", "FaustI"}]]];

countRecords[url_String] := Block[{f, $IterationLimit = \[Infinity]},

  f[str_, EndOfFile, c_] := c;
  f[str_, record_, c_] := f[str, Read[str, {Record}], c + 1];

  With[{str = OpenRead[url]},
   Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    Null
    ,
    f[str, Read[str, {Record}], 0]
    ,
    Close[str];
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

I use `` Internal`WithLocalSettings `` in order to have the stream closed even if the user aborts the execution.

Here a usage example:

```
countRecords["a.csv"]
```

> 30620

Comment: Is there a functional version of this, eg avoiding the internal increment c++, that looks a lot like the 1970s.

Comment: @alancalvitti Feel free to wrap a function around it yourself.

Comment: nope, I mean a functional alternative to the procedural method, with no iterators, only Map, Apply, recursion, etc.

Comment: @alancalvitti Recursion will likely hit the recursion limit and there is no list to `Map` on; actually, one does not want to have a list in memory here since the data in the file is _huge_. The point of handling streams lies within the fact that one wants to operate only on the current part of the stream.

Comment: There seem to be recursive approaches to stream processing, eg in Scala: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132924/functional-processing-of-scala-streams-without-outofmemory-errors, but I don't know Scala enough to analyze it.

Comment: @alancalvitti My point was that _Mathematica_ is not good at recursion because of the recursion limit. One could use tail recursion but one had to stretch oneself far more than just writing some lines of code as above. I never claimed that my approach was in any way elegant.  Honestly, I do not understand what problems you have with prodecural code.

Comment: Well, I'm writing a book Functional Data Workflow - have a whole chapter on why: referential transparency, avoiding mutable state, pipelining, modularity....

Comment: @alancalvitti Whatever it might be good for; I posted a recursive version.

Comment: nice, but it still has procedural parts (eg, "c+1", anything using `Set`)

Comment: @alancalvitti It's just ridiculous to try to avoid any plus operations in the code. Recall: We have to _count_ here something.